# Why isn't the backslash printed when I print the backreference?

Tags: regex, linux, perl

Why in the following snippet:

```
~$ perl -e '  
my $var = "SRC=array.c builtin.c eval.c field.c gawkmisc.c io.c \ main.c ";  
$var =~ /^\w+=(.*)/;  
print "$1\n";  
'  
array.c builtin.c eval.c field.c gawkmisc.c io.c  main.c
```

The `\` is not printed in the backreference. `.` obviously matches `\` in the string text since the capture is uptill the end of the line, so why isn't it printed?
Why would I need to escape it in this context?

Comment: One way to debug this is to print the target variable to see what's actually in it. :)

Comment: @briandfoy:I don't know how to do this. I just print the backreference

Comment: Sure you know how to do it. Right after you initialize the variable, `print $var`. Then you can see if what you think is in the variable is actually there before the operation you think is the problem.

Comment: minimal example: `perl -e 'my $var = "a \ b"; print $var'`

Answer (score 3):

The backslash character is special in that it indicates that what follows is not literal. For example, with text like `"line 1\nline 2\n"` you see two instances of `"\n"`... the backslash says what follows is a special meaning, and `n` indicates a carriage return. In your case, `"\ "` has no special meaning so only the space is printed.

If you truly want to see the backslash, `"\\"` will do it.

Answer (score 2):

The `"\  "` is considered an "escaped space". If you really want to see the `\`, you need `\\` in your string.

If you look closely at your output you will see

```
io.c  main.c
    ^^
```

There are **two** spaces...

So tiny change needed:

```
perl -e '
my $var = "SRC=array.c builtin.c eval.c field.c gawkmisc.c io.c \\ main.c ";  
$var =~ /^\w+=(.*)/;  
print "$1\n";  
'
array.c builtin.c eval.c field.c gawkmisc.c io.c \ main.c
```